# How to recalculate coordinates in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinates

í´ve moved several Points from my Survey file. Now i want to recalculate the new coordinates of those moved Points. And then Export it to Excel.
Does anybody have a quick answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$x` and `$y` from the Geometry section of the field calculator should add or update what you want in the attribute table.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a case for: Select all the points in your QGIS map window. Go to Excel or any other page. Paste.  Your new co-ordinates will be in the WKT field on the left.